# How to add a system call in RISC-V Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, riscv

It is well-documented on how to add a system call to Linux targeting x86, e.g. there is a file `/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl`.

I searched for the directory `entry` under `/arch/riscv` but did not find it. I tried to find if there is a file ends with `.tbl` under `/arch/riscv` but still did not find anything.

Is there any useful resource that describes how RISC-V Linux handles the system call and how we could add our own system calls to it? Or we could just ignore the `syscall_64.tbl` file?

Comment: You need to define the syscall number here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/riscv/include/uapi/asm/unistd.h. Then put the relevant SYSCALL_DEFINEx macro elsewhere. Just search for `*riscv_flush_icache` it can serve as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @oakad's comment. I did not try that approach, but found one useful [article](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/adding-syscalls.html#adding-a-new-system-call) that discusses about this:

> Some architectures (e.g. x86) have their own architecture-specific syscall tables, but several other architectures share a generic syscall table. Add your new system call to the generic list by adding an entry to the list in include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h

Adding to riscv is similar to x86, except that riscv does not have a syscall table. Hence, no need to add to the table for riscv. For the rest of the steps, follow this [link](https://dev.to/jasper/adding-a-system-call-to-the-linux-kernel-5-8-1-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-2ga8).